# What's the meaning of "I will not allow you to leave school over this"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The word "over" has many meanings but I can not understand what is the meaning of "over" here:

> I will not allow you to leave school over this.

I think I don't get the sentence's structure correctly.

The full text is here:

> He sighed and looked heavenward. “How
>   much will it cost to fix the tooth?”
>   “Fourteen hundred,” I said. “I’ll find the money.”
>   “The church will pay,” he said quietly. “I have a discretionary fund.”
>   “That money is sacred.”
>   The bishop threw his hands in the air. We sat in silence, then he opened
>   his desk drawer and withdrew a checkbook. I looked at the heading. It was
>   for his personal account. He filled out a check, to me, for fifteen hundred
>   dollars.
>   “**I will not allow you to leave school over this**,” he said.
>   The check was in my hand. I was so tempted, the pain in my jaw so
>   savage, that I must have held it for ten seconds before passing it back.

*Educated* by Tarawestover

Comment: **Over** can be used to mean **as a result of** (you could be fired *over* this) or **about** (don’t fuss over this), depending on the context.

Comment: Does "leave school" mean to drop out of school without degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

collinsdictionary.com, "over", meaning section #3, definition #4:

> You use **over** to indicate what a disagreement or feeling relates to or is caused by.
>   The women were making a fuss over nothing.
>   Synonyms: about, regarding, relating to, with respect to

It seems that "over" has about 30 meanings. Other definitions may also be relevant.

Comment: And Could you please explain to me what the meaning of the phrase is? (based on your chosen definition of "over")

Comment: @Peace “I will not allow you to leave school because of this”